# Determining application context from OWIN pipeline?

Tags: azure, owin, katana, nancy

I have an OWIN pipeline using Nancy:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseNancy();
    }
}
```

The UseNancy() is actually a call to my own custom extension method defined in this gist: https://gist.github.com/TheFastCat/0b7635d9e5795b44e72e

This code is executed both as an Azure Website or an Azure Cloud Service. Based on the context it is executing within I want to use a particular favicon, loaded as an embedded resource from a separate assembly. I do this by specifying separate NancyBootstrappers (each loading the proper favicon for its context).

1. Is there a more elegant solution to determining the runtime application that is executing the OWIN pipeline? Currently I check app.Properties["host.AppName"] ; however while the Website's app name matches it's assembly configuration, the CloudService app is the name of the Owin startup assembly.class. (see gist). It's cloogey.
2. Is there a more elegant/simple solution for specifying a custom favicon within Nancy for each of my web applications than creating separate bootstrappers and doing runtime application context checks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with the help of others on the https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/owin and https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/nancyfx chat boards

1. Yes. You can contextually check the OWIN host properties:

   if (app.Properties.ContainsKey("System.Net.HttpListener"))
   {
            // self hosted application context
   }

2.) Yes.

```
namespace ClassLib
{
    public class Startup() 
    { 
        public Startup(byte[] favIcon)  { ... }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) { ... }
    }
```

### }

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebHost.Startup))]
namespace WebHost
{
    public class Startup() 
    { 
        public voic Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            new ClassLib.Startup(webhostFavIcon).Configuration(app);
        }
    }
```

### }

```
namespace SelfHost
{
    private class Program() 
    { 
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(WebApp.Start(app => new ClassLib.Startup(selfHostFavIcon).Configuration(app))
            {}
        }
    }
}
```